# Confusing about char* in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const char* b="str";
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << *b << endl;
    cout << &b << endl;
    cout << *(&b) << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```sh
str
s
0x7ffdf39c27f0
str
```

I run my code on the web [runoob online compiler](https://www.runoob.com/try/runcode.php?filename=helloworld&type=cpp)

Why I get these results? I looked some questions about char*, but not enough for me to understand.   Can someone explain that to me? Pictures are best.

I want to know more about it with books or blogs recommended.

By the way, using`char b[]` instead of `const char*`, I get the same results.

---

Thanks a lot for all of you.

I just want to know why a char pointer's value is not an address.

I think adress is like 0x7ffdf39c27f0. an memory adress.

But `const char* b = "str"`. b is just `str`.

And I found that `*b` is the same as `*("str")`.

So I want to know what happened in the memory? why a char pointer's value is not an address?

Comment: What is it about these results that is confusing? You're printing a 0 terminated string, the first character of that string, the address of it, and then the string again.

Comment: It is always a good idea to state your expectations. It allows those who are answering to focus on specific mistakes or misconceptions and generally produces a better quality answer.

Comment: Confused. Is `b` a pointer or string? Based on definition, I would think `b` would return a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand what the code outputs, you need to understand that C++ output streams (objects with a type such as `std::ostream`) and therefore objects (such as `std::cout`) have a number of overloads of `operator<<()`.    The overload that is called depends on the type of argument provided.

I'll explain your second example, but the explanation for the first example is almost identical.

> ```
> const char* b="st\0r";
> cout << b << endl;
> cout << *b << endl;
> cout << &b << endl;
> cout << *(&b) << endl;
> ```

`cout << b` expands to `cout.operator<<(b)` where `b` has type `const char *`.   That overload of the operator function ASSUMES the argument points to (the first character of) a nul terminated string, which is represented in memory as an array of `char` that ends with a `char` with value `'\0'` (zero).   The operator function outputs each character it finds until it reaches a `'\0'` character.   The first `'\0'` found is the one YOU explicitly inserted after the `'t'`, so the output `st` is produced.    The fact that your string has a second `'\0'` after the `'r'` is irrelevant, since the operator function stops at the first one it finds.

`cout << *b` expands to a call of a different overload of `operator<<()` that accepts a single `char`, and outputs that `char`.   `*b` is the value of the first character in the string represented by `b`.   So the output `s` is produced.

In `cout << &b`, `&b` has type `const char **`  or (equivalently) `char const **`.   There is no overload of an output stream's `operator<<()` that accepts a `const char **`, but there is an overload that accepts a `const void *`.    Since any pointer (other than pointer-to-member or pointers to functions) can be implicitly converted to `void *`, that conversion is performed (by the compiler), so the overload matches, and is called.   That particular overload of the `operator<<()` prints the address in memory.

The implicit conversion in the third case doesn't happen in the first two cases, since a call that doesn't require an implicit conversion is a better match than a call which does.

In the last statement `*(&b)` is equivalent to `b`.  This is the case because `&` is the address-of operator in this code, and the `*` is the dereference operator (which is the inverse of the address-of operator).    So the last statement produces the same output as `cout << b`.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
cout << b << endl;
```

You are printing the string `b`

```cpp
cout << *b << endl;
```

You are printing the pointer that points to the first character of `b`., so is the same as:

```cpp
cout << b[0] << endl;
```

```cpp
cout << &b << endl;
```

`&b` is the memory address of `b`, which means the address memory to store `b` in the computer.

```cpp
cout << &b << endl;
```

So, you're printing the memory address of `b` here. The computer store `b` in the memory address `0x7ffdf39c27f0`, so that's what you get.

```
cout << *(&b) << endl;
```

You are printing a pointer that points to the memory of `b`, so you  print the value at the memory address of variable `b` which is the same as

```cpp
cout << b << endl;
```

edit: A pointer contains an *address* that (usually, it could point at a function, for example) represents the location of an object, and to print a pointer (usually) prints the *value* of that memory address. Because `char *` is intimately linked with null-terminated strings, there is a special overload for pointers to characters to print the pointed-at string.

A pointer variable is still a variable and will have an address of its own, so `&b` results in a pointer to a pointer, a  `char **` in this case and because it is no longer a `char *`, `cout << &b;` prints the address of `b`, not the address pointed at by `b` or the string pointed at by `b`.

Comment: Often important to make it clear that `b` is a null-terminated string and has none of the bells and whistles of a `std::string`. *`&b` is the memory address of `b`, which means the address memory to store `b` in the computer.* is 100% correct, but don't think it will be clear to someone coming in cold and doesn't realize the stark-to-us difference between the pointer and the pointed-at. Maybe one more sentence to beat the horse to death.

Comment: Much better, but mind if I tweak slightly?

Comment: @user4581301 Sure! Definitely, you can.

Comment: Took a bit more to round it all off than I expected.  Feel free to revert if I wandered too far from your intent.